# Using Windows Command Line with Python Subprocess Module

Tags: cmd, path, subprocess, python-3.4, spaces

So basically I've got the worst situation possible on Windows... A path with spaces on a drive other than C:/

I'm trying to run the following:

```
print(subprocess.check_call("cd d: && d: && " + '"' + dir_name + '"', shell=True))
```

Where `dir_name` is the name of the directory plus the name of the executable file. The way I get `dir_name` is as follows:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dir_name = (dir_path.replace("\\","/") + "/bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64/bowtie2-build").replace(" ", "\\ ")
```

I've also tried a few different variants of `dir_name`:

- `dir_path + "/bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64/bowtie2-build"`
- `dir_path.replace("\\","/")+"/bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64/bowtie2-build"`

I've tried it with and without quotes surrounding the whole thing, I've tried it with and without the `shell` option, I've tried it in `cmd.exe` and basically every time I get something along the lines of:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The full path is essentially:

```
D:/My Documents/2018 Documents/Class Name/Assignment Name/Subfile/ProgramName
```

With the variants I've tried being:

- `D://My Documents//2018 Documents//Class Name//Assignment Name//Subfile//ProgramName`
- `D:/My\ Documents/2018\ Documents/Class\ Name/Assignment\ Name/Subfile/ProgramName`
- `D://My\ Documents//2018\ Documents//Class\ Name/Assignment\ Name//Subfile//ProgramName`
- `"D:/My Documents/2018 Documents/Class Name/Assignment Name/Subfile/ProgramName"`
- `"D:/My\ Documents/2018\ Documents/Class\ Name/Assignment\ Name/Subfile/ProgramName"`
- `"D://My\ Documents//2018\ Documents//Class\ Name//Assignment\ Name//Subfile//ProgramName"`

I'm up for anything at this point, thank you so much in advance!

EDIT #1:

Based on comments, I should add that I'm trying to run `bowtie2-build` which is an extensionless program in the [Bowtie package](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml). It takes two command-line arguments, an input file and an output file name.

Comment: Use only backslash as the path separator for best compatibility with the CMD shell, i.e. `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` is good; stop there; the next line with the `replace` calls is wrong. Double-quote an executable path that contains spaces or special characters (except percent can't be escaped like this). Do not escape spaces with backslash; that's the path separator.

Comment: Basically, when I run `subprocess.check_call([dir_path+"/bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64/bowtie2-build"])`, I get `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` but I know that is it a valid application because I can run `bowtie2-build` from Git Shell and from Bash.

Comment: The actual filename is `bowtie2-build` no extension.

Comment: CMD won't  run an extensionless file unless "." is added to `PATHEXT`, and then it really should be a 32-bit or 64-bit PE executable, because `CreateProcess` doesn't support shebangs in scripts. If the latter fails, CMD will try `ShellExecuteEx` to open it as a registered filetype. While it's possible to associate an "open" action with "." (no extension) files, it's not a secure setup since this API doesn't check file security for execute access, unlike `CreateProcess`. It will try to execute any extensionless file you double click on in Explorer.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` only tries `CreateProcess`. If you need to run a file via `ShellExecuteEx`, you can use `os.startfile` if you don't need to pass command-line arguments. This is more secure than using `shell=True`, but if you need to pass parameters, then subprocess with `shell=True` is the easiest way. You could also call `ShellExecute[Ex]` directly via ctypes or PyWin32.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to pass 2 command-line args... Since I'm running a 3rd-party app I don't really have control over it being an executable or not. So basically, is it impossible to run it?

Comment: I got the following error: `"bowtie2-build.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available`. However, the version of the software I downloaded is `bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64`, which is specifically for 64-bit?

Comment: Okay... So weird thing here... (Not sure if this affects anything) `bowtie2-build` is actually a Python file? This would explain why it runs fine in bash because Python is an environmental variable there... Give me a few minutes to check if I can run it as a Python script.

Comment: Just ran it as this: `subprocess.check_call(["python", dir_path+"/bowtie2-2.3.4-mingw-x86_64/bowtie2-build", fasta, fasta.replace(".fasta", "")])` ... and it works. Sorry for wasting your time here, but if you write up your comments as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it since you led me in the right direction!